# Dismiss a Button once an inapp purchase has been successful - Ios - Swift - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

Im trying to dismiss a button after the in app purchase has been made and also make it not appear again once the user logs out or closes the app.
The purchase is successful in my code, but button remains.

```swift
@IBAction func inAppPurch(_ sender: Any) {
  if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
    // Can Make payments
    let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
    paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
    inAppPurch.isHidden = true
  } else {
    // Can't Make payments
    inAppPurch.isHidden = false
    print("cant make payments")
  }
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
  for transaction in transactions{
    if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
      //user payment successful
      print("Transaction successful!")
      UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: productID)

      SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
      // payment failed

      if let error = transaction.error {
        inAppPurch.isHidden = false
        let errorDescription = error.localizedDescription
        print("Transaction failed due to error: \(errorDescription)")
      }

      SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would have to store the status of purchase somewhere like UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get that bool in your `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` ... and deactivate with that bool value

```
 let id = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productID)
 button.isHidden = id
```

By default it return `false` so your button should not be hidden 
when you set it to true in `transaction.transactionState == .purchased` hide your button accordingly

then every time you go to the view controller it remains hidden

if you show your button code ... i will explain it better ... its just the idea .. how you can achieve that ...